# Why .NET MVC Change the order of Select List?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list in the view. I want it to be in an order as shown in the code below. But it changes it to as No comes first in runtime. Any thought why it happens or solution to fix it will be appreciated.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.AnyMissingPayment,
                      new List<SelectListItem>
                              {
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "Select" },
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" },
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false" }
                              },
                      new { @class = "form-control", 
                            id = "missingpayment", 
                            onchange = "checkMissingPayment()", 
                            required = "required", name =  "missingpayment" }
                     )
```

Comment: I tryied it , everything is fine

Comment: Somehow it changes the order when I run it and instead of Select - Yes - No, order goes like No - Select -Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selected=true attribute for the default row that you want to be selected.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.AnyMissingPayment,
                      new List<SelectListItem>
                              {
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "Select", Selected=true },
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" },
                                  new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false" }
                              },
                      new { @class = "form-control", 
                            id = "missingpayment", 
                            onchange = "checkMissingPayment()", 
                            required = "required", name =  "missingpayment" }
                     )
```

Comment: Sorry, then he does not need Select option